# Android: Merging two fragments

Tags: android

I am new to Android Development. I am using single FragmentActivity and it contains FrameLayout. I use many fragment classes.Some times when I replace one fragment to another their layouts are merge with each other. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Where is your code ? What you have tried ?

Comment: How about you think about what you're asking and imagine the following scenario: A person tells you this: "I am adding two numbers and the answer is wrong! what is wrong with my numbers? how can I make my numbers result in the right answer?".  That's all. Now you have to answer that question. You're good at Math, but that's all you are given. Now look at your question and POST SOME CODE so we can see what you're doing wrong and help you fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing the following ??

```
ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Where ft is your `FragmentTransaction`, and `fragmentManager` is your

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Comment: Yes I am doing same thing

Comment: Please tell me why the two fragments are overlapping?

Answer (score 0):

use `replace` to add new fragment

```
ft.replace(id,newfragment);
```

and remove the old fragment

```
ft.remove(old fragment);
```